# Sort images by dimensions

Tags: bash

I have several images with `ID-sequence.jpg` name where ID is same for a group of images, for example:

```
4fd-00027-1.jpg
4fd-00027-2.jpg
4fd-00027-3.jpg
6gq-00017-1.jpg
6gq-00017-2.jpg
6gq-00752-3.jpg
6gq-00752-4.jpg
```

.. and I need to move top 3 largest (by dimensions) images, but I can't quite figure how:

```
for file in 'ls -v *.jpg';
do
  IFS=: read -r width height < <(identify -ping -format '%w:%h' "$file")
  # how to compare each for dimensons?
  dir="/Users/eazzy/images_organized/${file%-*}"
  [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir "$dir"
  echo moving "$file" to "${file%-*}"
  mv "/Users/eazzy/images_trimmed/$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Where are you sorting the data?

Comment: @neuhaus thats what I don't get. In PHP I'd have created an array `$[ID]` (where ID in this case `6gq-00017` or `6gq-00752`) stored all images in it and did something like `min( array_column( $[ID], 'width' ) )` and `max( array_column( $[ID], 'height' ) )` inside a loop?

Comment: You can use the "sort" command offered by Unix. Just need one entry per line. See my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sorting by the Hypotenuse

You can calculate the hypotenuse with an [FX expression](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php):

```
identify -format '%[fx:hypot(w,h)] : %f\n' *.jpg
```

where `w` and `h` stand for *width* and *height* correspondingly; `%f` stands for *filename* (see [format and print image properties](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)).

*Sample output*

```
1280 : gentoo_matrix.jpg
738.756 : LA-Woman-048.jpg
2812.64 : passport-photo.jpg
1835.76 : spring_makeup-wallpaper-1600x900.jpg
1196.22 : woman_painting_study_by_warnerator-d4z4s6u.jpg
```

The next steps are trivial. Just sort in reverse human-numeric order and process the files in a loop:

```
identify -format '%[fx:hypot(w,h)] : %f\n' *.jpg | \
  sort -h -r | head -3 | \
  while read line; do
    file="${line#*: *}"
    echo "$file"
  done
```

*Sample output*

```
passport-photo.jpg
zh220.jpg
spring_makeup-wallpaper-1600x900.jpg
```

(top three files by hypotenuse).

Note, large numbers require special handling, as they are printed in scientific notation (see below).

### Sorting by the Area

Alternatively, you can calculate the area. The problem with the FX expressions is that big numbers are printed in scientific notation, e.g. `2.4576e+06` (`2457600`). You can handle this with `awk`'s `printf`, for instance:

```
identify -format '%[fx:w*h] : %f\n' *.jpg  | \
  awk -F: '{ printf("%d :%s\n", $1, $2); }' | \
  sort -n -r  | head -3 | \
  while read line; do
    file="${line#*: *}"
    echo "$file"
  done
```

Note, since the numbers are in the normal decimal notation (non-scientific), we don't need human-numeric sorting here. It is safe to invoke the direct numerical sorting with `sort -n`.

### The Case of a Large Number of Files

The `*.jpg` expression is expanded to a list of arguments by the shell. So if the number of images is very large, you should iterate them one-by-one, for instance:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*jpg$' -maxdepth 1 \
  -exec identify -format '%[fx:w*h] : %f\n' {} \; | \
  awk -F: '{ printf("%d :%s\n", $1, $2); }' | \
  sort -n -r  | head -3 | \
  while read line; do
    file="${line#*: *}"
    echo "$file"
  done
```

### Sorting within "Groups"

At the moment of writing, it was very unclear that you actually meant *taking top 3 images from **a group***, where *"group"* is a prefix like `${filename%-*}`, in your terms. So the real objective was to sort by groups, then by the image dimensions *within* the group.

The solution can be derived from what I have written above. We only need to apply the above to the groups:

```
process_group()
{
  group="$1"

  find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -iname "${group}-*.jpg" \
    -exec identify -format '%[fx:w*h] : %f\n' {} \; | \
    awk -F: '{ printf("%d :%s\n", $1, $2); }' | \
    sort -n -r  | head -3 | \
    while read line; do
      file="${line#*: *}"
      echo "$file"
    done
}

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*jpg$' -printf "%f\n" | \
  while read file ; do
    echo "${file%-*}"
  done | sort | uniq | while read group ; do
    process_group "$group"
  done
```

Comment: Great! Just not sure if this goes inside `for` cause I have 12k images in the folder and all with `[ID]-sequence` format.

Comment: @3zzy, no need in extra `for` here =)

Comment: I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/identify: Argument list too long` http://imgur.com/a/v04Wd

Comment: @3zzy, I've added a sample for large number of files at the end of the answer.

Comment: Hmm... still not working: http://imgur.com/a/TMmYK result: http://imgur.com/CNQUv12 ... it only moved three files

Comment: At least, the script has detected the "top 3". I have no idea regarding the rest of the logic. But it looks like the files are successfully moved to their directories.

Comment: @3zzy, wait, do you mean the script is supposed to move _more than three files_? But in the question you have written: _"...I need to move top 3 largest (by dimensions) images.."_

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. the folder has 12k images, and I need to move them all into individual folders named according to the ID in the image names.

Comment: @3zzy, fixed example with groups

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer to sort them by width:

```
identify -ping -format '%w %f\n' *.jpg |\
sort -rn |\
head -3 |\
awk '{print $2 }'
```

The "identify" command will output the width followed by the filename.

The "sort" command will sort the list numerically, largest number first

The "head" command will keep the first three entries

The "awk" command will print only the second item on each line which is the filename.

Comment: Yes but this again is for all files in a single folder? I have a folder with 12k images, and I need to move them all into individual folders named according to the ID in the image names.

Comment: Once you have the filenames you can use "mv" on them.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a list of top 3 images *in an each group*, as identified by the first 3 letters of the filename, sorted by their total area in pixels (i.e. width*height):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%f %[w] %[h]\n" '{}' ';' |\
 awk '// { print substr($1,0,4)" "$1" "$2*$3; }' |\
 sort -k1 -rnk3 | \
 awk '// { if(cgrp != $1) { cgrp=$1; cnt=0 } if(cnt++ < 3) { print  $1" "$2 } }'
```

This code implies that you have ImageMagick tools installed (should not be a problem on most *Nix systems)

(Note, if your image filenames are known to contain whitespace, you might need to modify this, to use TAB as the delimiter)

Comment: Yes but this again is for all files in a single folder? I have a folder with 12k images, and I need to move them all into individual folders named according to the ID in the image names.

Comment: > Yes but this again is for all files in a single folder? 

You can control the search depth with the "-maxdepth 1", just remove this argument, and it will process all the images in any nested folders too.

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to get top 3 images of an each group ? 

I.e. 3 largest images starting with 4fd, then 3 largest images starting with 6gq e.t.c.

If yes, please see my updated answer.